# PHP receiving a POST request from Java

Tags: java, php, post, web, httpurlconnection

EDIT: this is what is shown in my website logs
xx.xx.xxx.xx - - [27/Jan/2012:17:42:24 -0500] "POST /dir/addData2.php HTTP/1.1" 200 - www.mywebsites.com "-" "Java/1.7.0" "-"

I am hosting my website at 1&1, and I want to have page `blank.php` that should take a POST request and upload it to my database. I think I am sending my POST properly, and that somehow I am not handling it properly on my website. Because nothing is being inserted to my database.  The response has content length 0, but even if i send a header with the length of the string it wont change. Another option is that the host wont allow me to do remote post requests (still waiting on reply).

I send the post request from a Java application like this:

```
URL url = new URL("www.mywebsite.com/blank.php");    
HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
request.setRequestProperty("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setRequestMethod("POST");
OutputStreamWriter post = new OutputStreamWriter(request.getOutputStream());
String data = URLEncoder.encode("account", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(message[0], "UTF-8");
data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("message", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(message[2], "UTF-8");
data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("type", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(message[0], "UTF-8");
post.write(data);
post.flush();
/*
/ String example
/account=103&message=Feller+1391.88+0&type=103
*/
```

The response from the server is:

```
null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Date=[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 21:59:10 GMT]
Content-Length=[0]
Keep-Alive=[timeout=2, max=200]
Connection=[Keep-Alive]
Content-Type=[text/html]
Server=[Apache]
X-Powered-By=[PHP/5.2.17]
```

My webpage has this basic PHP code (right now, will improve/check for stuff later)

```
$link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $link);
$query = "INSERT INTO newData(account, message, type) VALUES('$_POST[account]', '$_POST[message]', '$_POST[type]')";
mysql_query($query) || die();
```

I want to point out that I do not have a private server, and I will probably use http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/examples.html later. Right now I just want to send a string from my Java application, receive it with PHP and insert to MySQL database.

Comment: Your question is vague. What's your concrete problem/question? That the response content length is 0? But you are not showing any PHP code which writes to the response?

Comment: Okay, my question is comparing my code and code examples everything looks the same but still on my database nothing is inserted. Not sure what you mean by writting to the response. My idea here is one way communication, application to server (which send automatic response, but I didnt think i had to reply to it). I am not able to write my own response, because its not my own server (share hosting)

Comment: Please do everything possible to take a look at the logs.  Access to the logs is *essential* for troubleshooting a web site.

Comment: Okay, ill send another request for logs. I agree with you they are essential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told the client code that this is a POST request. It will probably do a GET by default.

```
url = new URL(targetURL);
connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Comment: that was my first guess.  But the OP said he did a "setRequestMethod("POST")".  Maybe that was in his original post; maybe it was a subsequent edit.  I don't know.  But I *strongly* encourage the OP to *FIRST* "check all the basics" - check the logs, verify PHP, verify mysqL, verify PHP variables.  IMHO...

Comment: It was a subsequent edit (click on "edited X mins ago" to see the changes). Your suggestions all look good though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'm certain your ISP allows both "post" and "get" HTTP server requests.

Superficially, both your Java and PHP look "OK".

STRONG SUGGESTION:

1) Check your Apache logs on the server.

Make sure the request arrived (it probably did).

Check for errors (there could well be none for your request - but you SHOULD see SOMETHING in the Apache error log.

2) Verify PHP is working.

Writing a "hello world" page with "phpinfo ();" is a good way to do this.

3) Verify that MySQL is working.

Writing a "hello world" PHP page to verify you can 1) connect, 2) make a query, and 3) echo the query back in your web browser is ideal.

4) Verify that you can successfully read the "$_POST[account]" value you THINK you're getting from the client.

5) At that point, you should be able to:

a) have the client communicate with your server

b) read the post request and write it to your database

'Hope that helps .. and please post back with any specific questions/problems you might have.

Comment: PS: Modify your MySQL query with "|| die()", and echo the error message.  But *PLEASE* check the basics: Apache logs, PHP, MySqlConnectivity and PHP variables - first.

Comment: Sadly 1&1 doesnt allow me to see apache error logs, but they have this http://faq.1and1.com/miscellaneous/14.html (so far no entries on it). I have another webpage with a form, method post and same php code. Using the form I can insert elements into my database. I even copy strings from my java application and insert them. (I change mysql and php code to make it a simple as possible incase echoing or doing trivial stuff had anything to do)

Comment: The error link i send works now, but so far only shows the error when '$_POST[account]' is access without setting it first. (fix in real version in test version I added isset('$_POST[account]') (shouldnt show up again)

Comment: this is what is shown in my website logs xx.xx.xxx.xxx - - [27/Jan/2012:17:42:24 -0500] "POST /dir/addData2.php HTTP/1.1" 200 - www.mywebsites.com "-" "Java/1.7.0" "-"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not setting the request method on your HttpUrlConnection, and the default is GET. You'd need something like

```
request.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

If that doesn't work, I'd consider rather using the Apache HTTP client right away from the beginning, it's easiert to use than Java's standard HTTP client API.

Comment: I accidently took that line off when copying the code. (code is a little longer, and wanted to keep it short). Edit and added line